# What does "二人要通过许多小的管卡" mean?

Tags: meaning

From what I see from google, "管卡" is some sort of metal clamp? Would the phrase mean something like "the two of them passed through many small *mechnisms*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't that be 关卡 = checkpoints, barriers？

二人要通过许多小关卡

2 people must pass through many barriers

Some kind of fun sports competition.

Comment: Ah that would make sense. I suppose it was a mistype by the person.